# DB independent SOAP interface + MVC frontend done in PHP - advice needed

Tags: php, api, model-view-controller, soap, orm

I am looking at a new project at the moment that involves having a database independent interface (or as independent as possible - like PDO), and then the ability to add a front end, maybe using something like CodeIgniter, but should be possible to use other front ends like Windows GUIs or whatever.

I was thinking of using PHP SOAP together with PDO to put the database functions in place.  IS this a good approach? What are the pitfalls? Has anyone done anything similar and what would you advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described I understand you are looking at the following setup:

- a PHP SOAP and PDO based application to handle the database manipulation accessible as a service or through an API,
- Codeigniter / Windows GUI / anything else as a frontend which would communicate with the database manipulation system.

If that's what you are after, than it's a very nice separation of resposibility in the system. It allows you to keep the application / database independent from the front end on all levels which will make implementation of various clients much easier. It will basically become a typical server-client setup.

**Network performace and scalability**

The most important thing for you to consider will be the traffic you will be handling and scalability. If you are looking at client-server communication not within the local, fast-latency system, having clients send requests to the server application will be resource heavy on a big scale. My assumption is that the communication will take place mostly over some sort of internet protocol (probably HTTP) as oppose to local system calls. It's obviously much slower and resource heavy. Unless your particular project requires communication over the internet (like having a mobile application as one of the clients), I would strongly suggest to organize the client-server communication within the same OS or over some sort of fast-latency network.

**Code Performance**

Depending on how big is the volume of calls from the client to the server, you might need a non-standard PHP solution. The most common approach to web applications with PHP is having a web server (like Apache) to handle the HTTP requests correctly and than passing  the control through to PHP to further process the request (an than the web server again to send the reponse). The biggest downfall of this for your case is that the web server (in most cases) will have to bootstrap the PHP interpreter and all the source code of your database manipulation system for every client call. Starting from some point of scaling, it might be a big problem and will impact the costs of the project significantly. Proper benchmarking of server-side application will be required. If you are looking at an application big enough to care about problems like that, you will probably need to implement a standalone PHP application that can listen on specific ports turning into full-featured, stand-alone server application. This solution does not allow you to take advantage of common web servers, but enables you to create an application that bootstraps only once and is always ready to process client requests.

**Design**

From the design point of view, the most important thing to remember would be to always keep in mind which application is a server and which one is a client. With every feature of the system, you will need to make sure the right part is taking the resposibility. Don't implement any client-specific formatting or actions on the server-side. You will most likely want the data to be sent from the server in the rawest form possible and get the client application to process it to its needs. The only exception, would be when the processing part is so demand heavy that it's not possible for the client to handle it. That might be the case with some big volumes of data and clients for mobile devices. In that case it would smart to introduce some sort of bridge subsystem / application, that will handle processing on the server side before sending it the clinet.

I hope this will help you to make the right decision about your solution.